# XSL-FO page-master-alternatives sometimes exhausted

Tags: xsl-fo

I have a bit robust stylesheet for books. At the moment, I can’t figure out where could be the problem. My stylesheet sometimes works, sometimes not, depending on TOC’s lenght, which I can change dynamically with the number of levels I want to include in it.

**My stylesheets work this way (my intention is):**

Let the *Imprints* part starts on a *Title-Page*, ends on an even page, if the last page of the TOC is odd, put there a blank page after it:

```
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Imprints">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank" page-position="any"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Title-Page" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="first"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.CopyRight-Page" odd-or-even="even" page-position="rest"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.TOC" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="rest"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.TOC" odd-or-even="even" page-position="rest"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.TOC" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="last"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.TOC" odd-or-even="even" page-position="last"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
```

Let the main part, *Content-Pages*, starts on the first odd page after the TOC (or the blank page after it), let every chapter starts on the odd page after the previous chapter (last page or blank) and ends on an even page. If the last page should be odd, force a blank page (here I suppose could be the problem because I work with the whole part as well as particular chapters):

```
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Content-Pages">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right.First" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="first"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank" page-position="any"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Left" odd-or-even="even" page-position="rest"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="rest"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Left" odd-or-even="even" page-position="last"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="last"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
```

I call them this way (I am not sure what is the difference between `force-page-count="even"` and `force-page-count="end-on-even"`. I have checked some docs but it is still unclear to me):

```
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Imprints" force-page-count="even">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:TEI/tei:teiHeader" mode="draft"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster.CopyRight-Page">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="p">
                © Copyright!
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster.TOC">
        <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="//tei:TEI/tei:text" mode="toc"/>
            </fo:block>
        </fo:flow>
    </fo:page-sequence>
    <xsl:for-each select="//tei:div[@n='1']">
        <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Content-Pages" force-page-count="end-on-even">
            <fo:static-content flow-name="Region-Before-Left">
                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="running-header-left">
                    <fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="running-header-pageno-left">
                        <fo:page-number/>
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content><!-- Running header right -->
            <fo:static-content flow-name="Region-Before-Right">
                <fo:block xsl:use-attribute-sets="running-header-right">
                    <fo:inline xsl:use-attribute-sets="running-header-pageno-right">
                        <fo:page-number/>
                    </fo:inline>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:static-content flow-name="xsl-footnote-separator">
                <fo:block>
                    <fo:leader xsl:use-attribute-sets="footnote-separator"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:static-content>
            <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
            </fo:flow>
        </fo:page-sequence>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

When it fails and throws `Subsequences exhausted in page-sequence-master "Content-Pages", cannot recover. (No context info available)`, it helps to change `force-page-count` or to add another one reference to `PageMaster.Page-Right.First` and make it possible on `even` pages. With that chapters sometimes start on **odd** pages but have page numbers (which they should not). Really confusing.

Even adding:

```
<fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right.First" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="rest"/>
```

… does not help.

I use the last Saxon HE and Apache FOP 1.1.

**UPDATE**

Progress according to @Tony_Graham:

```
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Imprints">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Title-Page" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="first"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.CopyRight-Page" odd-or-even="even" page-position="rest"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.TOC"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
        </fo:page-sequence-master>
        <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Content-Pages">
            <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right.First" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="first"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Left" odd-or-even="even" page-position="rest"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="rest"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Left" odd-or-even="even" page-position="last"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right" odd-or-even="odd" page-position="last"/>
                <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
            </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
```

And the rest:

```
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="Imprints" force-page-count="end-on-even">
...

<fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster.CopyRight-Page" initial-page-number="auto-odd">
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `force-page-count="end-on-even"` on the `fo:page-sequence` **before** every `fo:page-sequence` that you want to start on an odd page.  Alternatively, set `initial-page-number="auto-odd"` on the `fo:page-sequence`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#initial-page-number

`force-page-count="even"` means that if the page-sequence started on an even page, it would end on an odd page to make it an even number of pages, and vice-versa if it started on an odd page.  `force-page-count="end-on-even"` would finish on an odd page irrespective of if the page-sequence started on an odd or an even page.  (AH Formatter has extensions to end on 'doubly-even', and more besides, and to force the page count for the entire document to end on an even page, etc.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf63/ahf-ext.html#axf.force-page-count)  However, it's likely that `initial-page-number` will do what you need.

Also:

1. You don't need to repeat `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` with two different `odd-or-even` to select the same page-master.  That's the same as one `fo:conditional-page-master-reference` with no `odd-or-even` since the default value is `any`.  See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#odd-or-even.
2. You can drop explicit `page-position="any"` since that's the default anyway.
3. "Imprints" has two 'odd-or-even="even" page-position="rest"', so the second will never be used.
4. Selecting the same "PageMaster.TOC" for odd/even and rest/last could be reduced to just `page-position="any"`.

**UPDATE**

You can change your current `fo:page-sequence-master`s to:

```
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Imprints">
        <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Title-Page" page-position="first"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.CopyRight-Page" odd-or-even="even" page-position="rest"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.TOC"/>
        </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Content-Pages">
        <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right.First" page-position="first"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Left" odd-or-even="even"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right" odd-or-even="odd"/>
        </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
```

Within `fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives`, "the conditions are tested in order from the beginning of the sequence of children", so you want to put the least likely alternatives first. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_repeatable-page-master-alternatives)  You also want to have a catch-all alternative at the end, but you've got that covered.

However, I don't understand why "Imprints" includes "PageMaster.CopyRight-Page" and "PageMaster.TOC" when the copyright page and the ToC are each in separate page-sequences that refer to specific page-masters.  You may want something more like:

```
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Imprints">
        <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Title-Page"/>
        </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="TOC">
        <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.TOC"/>
        </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="CopyRight-Page">
        <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.CopyRight-Page"/>
        </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
    </fo:page-sequence-master>
    <fo:page-sequence-master master-name="Content-Pages">
        <fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Blank" blank-or-not-blank="blank"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right.First" page-position="first"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Left" odd-or-even="even"/>
            <fo:conditional-page-master-reference master-reference="PageMaster.Page-Right" odd-or-even="odd"/>
        </fo:repeatable-page-master-alternatives>
...
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="Imprints">
...
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="CopyRight-Page" initial-page-number="auto-odd">
...
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="PageMaster.TOC" initial-page-master="auto-odd">
...
<xsl:for-each select="//tei:div[@n='1']">
    <fo:page-sequence master-reference="Content-Pages" initial-page-number="auto-odd">
```

Comment: Tanks a lot! However, I still can’t make that to work. It works if I don’t specify whether the page should have a particular `page-position`. If so, the pdf is generated but the rule for the first page is ignored. I set `force-page-count="end-on-even"` to *Imprints* part, added `initial-page-number="auto-odd` to *Content-Pages*, shortened the *Imprints* part according to your advice. Still exhausted. I am a bit confused how to rearrange masters for the rest of the document. I have also updated the question with the code improved.

Comment: Thanks, it seems it could really work! As for the *Imprints*, the intention is the structure should be always the same, without any variations—one title page (odd), one copyright page (even), TOC of flexible length (even/odd/blank).

Comment: So the title page's page-sequence would just need to refer to "PageMaster.Title", and the copyright page's page-sequence to "PageMaster.CopyRight-Page".  You could then drop the "Imprints" and "CopyRight-Page" `fo:page-sequence-master`.